# Render form errors with the label rather than field name

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to list all form errors together using {{ form.errors }} in the template.  This produces a list of form fields and nested lists of the errors for each field.  However, the literal name of the field is used. The generated html with an error in a particular field might look like this.

```
<ul class="errorlist">
    <li>
        target_date_mdcy
        <ul class="errorlist">
            <li>This field is required.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like use the errorlist feature, as it's nice and easy.  However, I want to use the label ("Target Date", say) rather than the field name.  Actually, I can't think of a case in which you would want the field name displaying for the user of a webpage.  Is there way to use the rendered error list with the field label?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't see a simple way to do this.

The errors attribute of the form actually returns an `ErrorDict`, a class defined in `django.forms.utils` - it's a subclass of `dict` that knows to produce that ul rendering of itself as its unicode representation.  But the keys are actually the field names, and that's important to maintain for other behavior.  So it provides no easy access to the field labels.

You could define a custom template tag that accepts the form to produce the rendering you prefer, since in Python code it's easy to get the field label given the form and the field name.  Or you could construct an error list by label in the view, add it to your context, and use that instead.

*edit*
Alternately again, you can iterate over the fields and check their individual errors, remembering to display `non_field_errors` as well.  Something like:

```
<ul class="errorlist">
  {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <li>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</li>
  {% endif %}
  {% for field in form %}
    {% if field.errors %}
      <li>
        {{ field.label }}
        <ul class="errorlist">
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You might want to wrap non_field_errors in a list as well, depending.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  I didn't know that about ErrorDict.  I went with custom filter, as I'll probably resuse it.

Answer (score 9):

I know this has already been answered but, I ran across the same scenario and found there is a simple way to use the label:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <ul class="user-msg error">
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <li>
              {% if field != '__all__' %}
                <strong>{{ field.label }}:</strong>
              {% endif %}
              {{ error }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: great answer, the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) are pretty helpful regarding this too.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in a custom form class which all my forms inherit instead of `django.forms.Form`. There I change the way `form.errors` works by returning a custom `ErrorDict` whose `as_ul` method takes labels into account. Thus you don't need to change your templates, but you need to have your forms inherit `CustomBaseForm`.

```
class CustomErrorDict(ErrorDict):
    def __init__(self, form, iterable=None, **kwargs):
        self.form = form
        super(CustomErrorDict, self).__init__(iterable, **kwargs)

    def as_ul(self):
        if not self:
            return u''

        def humanify(field_name):
            try:
                return self.form.fields[field_name].label or field_name
            except:
                return field_name

        # main logic is copied from the original ErrorDict:
        return mark_safe(u'<ul class="errorlist">%s</ul>'
                % ''.join([u'<li>%s%s</li>' % (humanify(k), force_unicode(v))
                    for k, v in self.items()]))

class CustomBaseForm(forms.Form):
    @property
    def errors(self):
        return CustomErrorDict(self, super(forms.Form, self).errors)

    ... rest of CustomBaseForm ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django import forms

def my_clean(self):
    self.my_errors = ''
    for x in self.visible_fields():
        if x.errors:
            self.my_errors += "<p>%s: %s</p>" % (x.label, x.errors)


class SetPwdForm(forms.Form):
    pwd= forms.CharField(label='password', required=True, min_length=6)
    def clean(self):
        ...
        my_clean(self)
```

**use *myform.my_errors* in views.**

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is looking do something like this using the `django.contrib.messages` framework in, for example, a `FormView`:

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    for field, errors in form.errors.items():
        for error in errors:
            messages.error(
                self.request,
                form.fields[field].label + ": " + error
            )
```

Note this is just a basic template, you'll have to take care of non-field errors et cetera in your code in the case where `form.fields[field]` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach shows `verbose_name` instead of the field name.
It can be used in `get_context_data()` too but personally, I prefer this way:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist


class ShowVerboseNameInFormsMixin:

    def add_error(self, field, error):
        super(ShowVerboseNameInFormsMixin, self).add_error(field, error)
        for field, message in self._errors.copy().items():
            try:
                verbose_name = self._meta.model._meta.get_field(field).verbose_name
                del self._errors[field]
                self._errors[verbose_name] = self.error_class()
                self._errors[verbose_name].extend(message)
            except FieldDoesNotExist:
                pass
```

and then use it like this:

```py
from django import forms


class FooForm(ShowVerboseNameInFormsMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

with a little extra code, It can show the `__all__` to `all` or any other intended string.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the filter I used to render an error list with the field label, following Peter's suggestion.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.template import Library, Context, loader
register = Library()

@register.filter
def form_error_list(form):

    result = ""    
    if form.errors:
        fields = form.fields
        error_items = []
        for error_field in form.errors:
            label = fields[error_field].label
            if not label:
                label = ' '.join([word.capitalize() for word in error_field.split('_')])
            errors = form.errors[error_field]
            error_li = ''.join(['<li>{0}</li>'.format(error) for error in errors])
            error_items.append({'label': label, 'error_li': error_li})    
        inner = ''.join(['<li>{0}<ul class="errorlist">{1}</ul></li>'.format(item['label'], item['error_li']) for item in error_items])
        result = mark_safe('<ul class="errorlist">{0}</ul>'.format(inner))

    return result
```

Comment: That will throw an exception if you have any non-field errors - for the full general case you'll want to allow for the possibility that a key in `form.errors` is not actually a field name.  And now that I look into the code, the values of the `ErrorDict` are instances of `ErrorList`, a class which has a `as_ul` method that can construct your `error_li` method and the surrounding `ul` element, with escaping enabled - so you could just do `error_li = errors.as_ul()`